# How to run a package from other package?

Tags: java

I want to run a package from other package of the same project, more exactly, I have 2 files(the first is a simple file, the second is a `JFrameForm`), I created a button in `JFrameForm`, and when it is pressed, I want Java to run "the first file". And a don't know how to do this. Please help.

Comment: You don't "run a package". Import the class and either instantiate and use, or use if it's only static methods.

Comment: What do you mean by "run package"?

Comment: You mean class or package ?!!

Answer (score 1):

You don't "run packages". You execute methods. You could say you "run the main class", which would mean running the `public void main(String[] args)` method.